# .htaccess modrewrite friendly url

Tags: .htaccess

I've searched on Google to find a way to make my URL friendly to my users.
My url now is this:

> http://www.rasolutions.nl/blogitem?id=2&name=newpages

I would like it to be like this:

> http://www.rasolutions.nl/blogitem/2/newpages

I used Google to find something like that, my result:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^blogitem/([0-9]+)-([a-z]+) http://rasolutions.nl/blogitem?id=$1&name=$2 [NC]
```

Sorry for the bad English, I'm Dutch and my English isn't the best.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write in your .htaccess some think like:

```
RewriteEngine on 
# ! Warning ! 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/cms/base/tools/urlmodifier.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cms/base/tools/urlmodifier.php?param=$1 [L,QSA]
```

... and do redirect in urlmodifier.php with including of file from request url and modifications of $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].

Comment: Thank you, I've done some more searching and came with the following code: Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule blogitem/^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /blogitem?id=$1&name=$2 [L]

Comment: yes, but your decision can't to translate both variants: friendly and unfriendly.